# Calling user defined functions from dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

I'm working on a project that involves many different tibbles, all of which have a `period` variable of the format YYYYMM. Below is an example of how all my tibbles look like:

```r
tibble_1 <- tibble::tibble(
  period = c(201901, 201912, 201902, 201903),
  var_1 = rnorm(4),
  var_2 = rnorm(4)
)
```

But for some operations (i.e. time series plots) it's easier to work with an actual Date variable. So I'm using mutate to transform the period variable into a date like follows:

```r
tibble_1 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    date = lubridate::ymd(stringr::str_c(period, "01"))
)
```

Since I will be doing this a lot, and the date transformation is not the only mutation I am going to be doing when calling `mutate`, I'd like to have a user-defined function that I can call from within the `mutate` call. Here's my function:

```r
period_to_date <- function() {
  lubridate::ymd(stringr::str_c(period, "01"))
}
```

Which I would later call like this:

```r
tibble_1 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    date = period_to_date()
)
```

Problem is, R can't find the period object (which is not really an object on itself, but part of the `tibble`).

```
> Error in stri_c(..., sep = sep, collapse = collapse, ignore_null = 
TRUE) : object 'period' not found
```

I'm pretty sure I need to define a data-mask so that the envir in which `period_to_date` is executed can look for the object in it's parent envir (which should always be the caller envir since the `tibble` containing the `period` column is not always the same), but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function does not know which object you want to modify. Pass the `period` object in the function and use it like :

```
period_to_date <- function(period) {
  lubridate::ymd(stringr::str_c(period, "01"))
  #Can also use
  #as.Date(paste0(period,"01"), "%Y%m%d")
}

tibble_1 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(date = period_to_date(period))

#  period   var_1  var_2 date      
#   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <date>    
#1 201901 -0.476  -0.456 2019-01-01
#2 201912 -0.645   1.45  2019-12-01
#3 201902 -0.0939 -0.982 2019-02-01
#4 201903  0.410   0.954 2019-03-01
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak!! It works. I thought R was automatically going to look for it in the caller environment. Guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Consider passing the column name as an argument to your function:

```r
library(dplyr)


period_to_date <- function(x) {
  lubridate::ymd(stringr::str_c(x, "01"))
}

df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, period = c('201903', '202001', '201511'))

df %>% mutate(p2 = period_to_date(period))
#>   x period         p2
#> 1 1 201903 2019-03-01
#> 2 2 202001 2020-01-01
#> 3 3 201511 2015-11-01
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>